# How to convert a part of nested arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays

I would like to know how to convert apart of nested arrays.

```
csv = CSV.parse(csv_string)

csv = csv.each{|rec_upd_date|
  rec_upd_date = rec_upd_date.slice(8,2) + "/" + rec_upd_date.slice(5,2) + "/" + rec_upd_date.slice(0,4);
  puts rec_upd_date
}

for rec_upd_date in csv do
  rec_upd_date = rec_upd_date.slice(8,2) + "/" + rec_upd_date.slice(5,2) + "/" + rec_upd_date.slice(0,4);
end
```

After I executed code like above like, I encountered an error:

> no implicit conversion of String into Array (TypeError).

I would like to know how I can convert a part of nested arrays without experiencing an error like above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looping over an array with `each` does not change it. Even if you override the loop variable (`rec_upd_date`) it does not change the actual value.

In order to mutate an array you should use [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-map):

```
csv = csv.map do |rec_upd_date|
  "#{rec_upd_date.slice(8,2)}/#{rec_upd_date.slice(5,2)}/#{rec_upd_date.slice(0,4)}"
end
```

The return value of each iteration will be the value of the respective item in the resulting array.

or, you can shorten this with the change in-place version of [`map!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-map-21):

```
csv.map! do |rec_upd_date|
  "#{rec_upd_date.slice(8,2)}/#{rec_upd_date.slice(5,2)}/#{rec_upd_date.slice(0,4)}"
end
```

For example:

```
csv = ["2015-03-20 10:17:20 +0200", "2015-04-14 10:17:20 +0200", "2013-12-24 10:17:20 +0200"]
csv = csv.map do |rec_upd_date|
  "#{rec_upd_date.slice(8,2)}/#{rec_upd_date.slice(5,2)}/#{rec_upd_date.slice(0,4)}"
end
# => ["20/03/2015", "14/04/2015", "24/12/2013"]
```

---

For an input like:

```
[["03/20/2015", A, B],["06/03/2015", C, D],
 ["04/22/2015", E, F],["03/20/2015", A2, B2],
 ["06/03/2015", C2, D2],["01/03/2015", E2, F2],
 ["12/20/2015", A3, B3],["11/05/2015", C3, D3],
 ["07/15/2015", E3, F3]]
```

and you want to change only the first element of each item:

```
[["20/03/2015", A, B],["03/06/2015", C, D],
 ["22/04/2015", E, F], ...]
```

the simplest solution will be to return an array for each iteration:

```
csv.map do |arr|
  [do_something_to(arr[0]), arr[1], arr[2]]
end
```

Another option is, to set the first element of each array item. Since you are not trying to *replace* the item, but only to *modify* it, using `each` will work:

```
csv.each do |arr|
  arr[0] = do_something_to(arr[0])
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your clarification. My actually intended conversion of array of arrays; ["30/20/2015", "14/04/2015", "24/12/2013"]

Comment: What I would ultimately like to do is to convert like next;
[["03/20/2015", A, B]["06/03/2015", C, D]["04/22/2015", E, F]["03/20/2015", A2, B2]["06/03/2015", C2, D2]["01/03/2015", E2, F2]["12/20/2015", A3, B3]["11/05/2015", C3, D3]["07/15/2015", E3, F3]]
 →
[["20/03/2015", A, B]["03/06/2015", C, D]["22/04/2015", E, F]["20/03/2015", A2, B2]["03/06/2015", C2, D2]["03/01/2015", E2, F2]["20/12/2015", A3, B3]["05/11/2015", C3, D3]["15/07/2015", E3, F3]]

Answer (score 0):

You should do this:

```
csv.each { |rec_upd_date|
  rec_upd_date = rec_upd_date.slice(8,2).to_s + "/" + rec_upd_date.slice(5,2).to_s + "/" + rec_upd_date.slice(0,4).to_s
  puts rec_upd_date
}
```

**What was wrong?**

Try following code:

```
csv.each { |rec_upd_date|
  puts rec_upd_date.class
}
#Array
#Array
...
#Array
```

Since the `csv` is an Array of Array, the method `slice` is not [String#slice](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/String.html#method-i-slice), rather its [Array#slice](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-slice).

Now as official Array#slice document states (emphasis mine):

> Returns the element at index, or returns a subarray starting at the
>   start index and continuing for length elements, or returns a *subarray*
>   specified by range of indices

The returned value of `rec_upd_date.slice(8,2)`, `rec_upd_date.slice(5,2)` and `rec_upd_date.slice(0,4)` is an Array. As you are trying to add an Array to a String `"/"`,  its throwing the TypeError.

Using [to_s](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-to_s) we are converting the Array first into a String and then adding to another String. Hence no error is generated.